# How to make componentWillUnmount work?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs

I am trying to understand how componentWillUnmount works in reactjs. Does it get called automatically or do we need to manually call unmountComponentAtNode to make it work?

I am using reactjs with angular and rendering the parent component inside the directive. Now, what I want is that when I change the route, I want my parent component's componentWillUnmount to run and do the necessary cleanup before ng-view is replaced with another directive containing another parent component.

Answer (score 3):

It will be called automatically.

http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount

Comment: i  did go through the official doc before about componentWillUnmount and was under the assumption that it will  be called automatically.However, it doesn't.

Comment: According to doc "Invoked immediately before a component is unmounted from the DOM." My query is that when  is the component unmounted from dom and what triggers this action?

Comment: How are you testing whether it's getting unmounted?

Comment: i tried placing  the breakpoint as well as a console log.but neither seems to work

Comment: Are you navigating away to a totally separate page and seeing if it fires?  Are you writing a SPA?

Comment: I am using reactjs with angular and rendering the parent component inside the directive.Now, what I want is that when i change the route , I want my parent component's componentWillUnmount to run and do the necessary cleanup before ng-view is replaced with another directive  containing another  parent component

Comment: Yes, I am writing a SPA and trying to navigate to a separate tab

Comment: The React component within an Angular directive could be muddying the waters and have no experience mixing the two. My guess would be that this is the source of your issue but I can't be certain.

Comment: Also, update your question with the fact you're using a React component within an Angular directive, as it this changes the question significantly.